# How does writing to common queue aid in resolving concurrency issues

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3865121/1071840

I understand that if multiple threads will push the requests to a single queue and a buffer write thread will have exclusive access to read/update the queue.. then this queue can be concurrently written to and read from and we'll achieve lockless serialization.

But my question is won't the threads need to acquire lock on the queue itself. I wish to maintain the order in which requests were made.

[It's not a homework question. I'm just trying to understand how do we alleviate concurrency issues in multithreaded environments with asynchronous writes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my question is won't the threads need to acquire lock on the queue itself.

Not necessarily.  There are concurrent queue implementations (such as [this one in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), or this implementation in the [PPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx)) which are either entirely lockless, or use much finer grained locking than locking on the entire queue.  This can dramatically improve the overall throughput.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I'll read through..might have more questions :)

Comment: @user1071840 It's likely that the log is buffered, and if it's going to IO, will basically perform the best if written to by a single thread.  By having an efficient concurrent queue, you can allow writers to write to the queue quickly, and have a single worker pull the items out as they come and write to disk.  This tends to eliminate/reduce the contention, as the contention for the queue will be much lower (or nothing) compared to the contention for the write buffer.